# Blank Screen with Google Android Maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps

I tried this sample tutorial from this site http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html
I am getting blank screen when I tested it in samsung galaxy grand. 
Can anyone help me with the sample code for map integration?
I've to accept that I am very new to this Maps integration

Comment: Can you show the codes?

Comment: include the logcat... if u follow the tutorial perfectly, then u wont have any errors....

Comment: without code its not possible to help you. don't post links to tutorials post what you have done.

Comment: Gen your own key and try again

Comment: Yes I tried with my own key only

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert you map api key in place of map api key of sample to test it over your machine